# LIstView builder wrapped with Padding, without cropping

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to achieve padding on the left of a ListViewBuilder but whenever I add the padding and a user scrolls the list (horizontal axis) you can see the padding clearly:

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                     separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                     itemCount: 4,
                     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                           height: 100,
                           width: 100,
                           color: Colors.grey,
                        );
                     },
              )
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a padding property on the ListView.seperator()

```
  child: ListView.separated(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
```